Linktime memory usage
I'm trying to compile a small C program. But it requires ocaml libraries when compiling.  During compiling, all my 16 gigabytes of RAM run out in 10 seconds, which is why I cannot build the program.  Is this normal behavior and is it possible to somehow reduce memory consumption?

Realized that the problem occurs when trying to link an object file produced by the ocaml compiler
